# How to perform aggregate or function for fields present in different model but inter-related?

Tags: python, django

This is my code

```
class ledger1(models.Model):
    Creation_Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    group1_Name = models.ForeignKey(group1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Opening_Balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)   
    Total_Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Total_Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accounting_double_entry:ledgerdetail", kwargs= 
         {'pk':self.pk})




class journal(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField()
    By = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,)
    Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.By)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accounting_double_entry:detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

I was wondering how can I perform aggregate function for Debit and Credit field (which is under journal model) in order of which falls under ledger

If I perform aggregate function in general it will give the total amount of debit and credit present in journal but I dont want that I want It should give the total amount which is present for a particular ledger...

For Example: If there is a total of 5 Debit entries I made, and
suppose I have created a ledger name Bank Account where there is only 3 Debit entries of journal is related. I want to calculate the total of those 3 entries not all 5 entries...

I have made foreign key relations for TO and By fields in journal model...

Actually I want to perform a double-entry-acccounting system through my app...

it will a real help if anyone can find me the solution for this..

Thank you..

Comment: Is it possible to clean up the models a bit? Furthermore it is not really clear *which* `Journal`s you want to aggregate? These through the `to`, or `by` relation?

Comment: Yeah I have edited it right now...I just want to  calculate the total debits which are related in ledger through By field .same for credit ...The result will be reflected in total debit and total credit column of ledger